# Is there any relationship between logistics regression and decision tree?

Tags: r, statistics, decision-tree

I tried to make a decision tree, and predict the result of the tree with predict function.

`predict(c.tree1,D1, type = "prob")`

when the type is "prob" it will give you back the probability of getting result instead of simple classify it. I think it is pretty close to logistic regression.

Could you please tell me is there any relationship between them?

Comment: Probably better to ask this on http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask question related to concepts there is different website of stack over flow.

Logistic regression is used only when our dependent variable is binary (0,1,Yes,NO,etc).
but decision tree can be used if dependent variable is discrete or binary(categorical).

In short logistic is used for classification and decision tree is used for both regression and classification.

hope answer to your question.